# CTE JSON Merge Patches in SQLite?

Tags: sql, json, sqlite, common-table-expression

So say I have a set of json merge patches

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `patch` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `events` (`id`, `entity_id`,`patch`) VALUES
(1534547094302351260,5619707354218640809, '{}')
(1534547094302351360,5619707354218640809,'{
         "title": "Goodbye!",
         "author" : {
       "givenName" : "John",
       "familyName" : "Doe"
         },
         "tags":[ "example", "sample" ],
         "content": "This will be unchanged"
       }
'),
(1534547095749386320,5619707354218640809,'{
         "title": "Hello!",
         "phoneNumber": "+01-123-456-7890",
         "author": {
       "familyName": null
         },
         "tags": [ "example" ]
       }');
```

Per [@forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas)  request I'd hope for something like

| entity_id | patch |
| --- | --- |
| 5619707354218640809 | '{"title": "Hello!","author" : {"givenName" : "John"},"tags": [ "example" ],"content": "This will be unchanged","phoneNumber": "+01-123-456-7890"}' |

So currently I'm reading the patches in a select and applying them via [json_patch](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jpatch) but I was hoping to turn into a RECURSIVE CTE so I wasn't loading and binding each patch individually.  In the example there are only 2 patches but I can have 100s per `entity_id`.

I'd like to merge these together into a single result. Originally I thought about useing CTE recursion but all examples I can see use UNION ALL which isn't reducing on a single value. I'm a big lost, any ideas?

Comment: Your expected result is just the last row of your sample data. Is this what you want? The most recent row for each entity_id?

Comment: @forpas I went into more detail with a better exarmple.

Comment: Did you ever work out a way to do this, @Delaney?

Comment: @hatfinch no, end up doing merge work outside in my own process